# @font-face not loading in a font?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am having a hard time getting the Burbank font to load in on my website. I have downloaded it off the internet in an opentype font file named burbank-big-condensed-black.otf , This file is inside of a zip file named burbankblack.zip , and all of this is in a file named fonts. I tried to put this into my website using this code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Burbank';
  src: url('fonts/burbankblack.zip/burbank-big-condensed-black.otf');
}

.menu a {
  font-family: 'Burbank', sans-serif;
}
```

This results in the font only being changed to sans-serif. Is there anything i need to do that may help me get to get the font on my site, or is there something i need to change?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to let the server extract the otf font from a zip file. I would put the unzipped font files into a folder and reference those.

Answer (score 0):

That it's not a valid path for the src, `burbankblack.zip`, extract the font from the .zip, or delete the `.zip`.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Burbank';
  src: url('fonts/burbankblack/burbank-big-condensed-black.otf');
}
```

Comment: Inside that .zip is the font, you need to extract it, not deleted. you know were the burbank-big-condensed-black.otf file is?

Comment: I moved the burbank-big-condensed-black.otf file out of the zip and into the font folder

Comment: Perfect, use this ->  src: url('fonts/burbank-big-condensed-black.otf');

Answer (score 0):

Unzip it and upload it as a folder to a website directory, you need a correct location, best click on a font folder > properties > file location and copy the right path.